# Feature request to allow executable XSLT code snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

For questions related to HTML/JavaScript/CSS, Stack Overflow allows you to embed executable code snippets in a question and/or answer.

I would suggest to allow that too for XSLT questions: XSLT 1.0 is supported directly by the browsers, and for XSLT 3 there is a free-to-be-used JavaScript library with [SaxonJS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) [available](https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml). Using this library it is possible to run XSLT 3 in the browser easily. Find below some demonstrations where I exploit the JavaScript snippet feature to do that; of course in the Stack Overflow XSLT snippets editor, I would expect the XML or JSON input and the XSLT input not to be inserted in `script` elements, but in an editor provided. Also the result(s), instead of being displayed in a textarea, could as well be rendered in case of HTML and/or shown as code blocks in case of XML or JSON or HTML.

The advantages of this would be huge to the community of XSLT questions and answers on Stack Overflow as it would allow most people asking to provide a minimal, but complete, sample demo of the sample input and XSLT they have as well as allowing most answers to include an executable demonstration of the proposed XSLT code to solve the problem raised in the question.

### XML to HTML transformation

```js
transform(
  document.getElementById('Input').textContent,
  document.getElementById('XSLT').textContent,
  'XML',
  document.getElementById('Result'),
  document.getElementById('Results')
);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98%;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.5/SaxonJS2.js"></script>

<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt-so-snippets/transform.js"></script>

<script id="Input" type="application/xml">
<cities>
  <city name="Milano"  country="Italia"      pop="5"/>
  <city name="Paris"   country="France"      pop="7"/>
  <city name="München" country="Deutschland" pop="4"/>
  <city name="Lyon"    country="France"      pop="2"/>
  <city name="Venezia" country="Italia"      pop="1"/>
</cities>
</script>

<script id="XSLT" type="application/xslt+xml">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:template match="cities">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>City List</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="city" group-by="@country">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
          <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/@name">
              <xsl:sort select="."/>
              <xsl:if test="position() ne 1">, </xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@pop)"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>XSLT grouping example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>XSLT grouping example</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</script>

<select id="Results"></select>
<textarea id="Result"></textarea>
```

### XML to HTML transformation: result documents

```js
transform(
  document.getElementById('Input').textContent,
  document.getElementById('XSLT').textContent,
  'XML',
  document.getElementById('Result'),
  document.getElementById('Results')
);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98%;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.5/SaxonJS2.js"></script>

<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt-so-snippets/transform.js"></script>

<script id="Input" type="application/xml">
<cities>
  <city name="Milano"  country="Italia"      pop="5"/>
  <city name="Paris"   country="France"      pop="7"/>
  <city name="München" country="Deutschland" pop="4"/>
  <city name="Lyon"    country="France"      pop="2"/>
  <city name="Venezia" country="Italia"      pop="1"/>
</cities>
</script>

<script id="XSLT" type="application/xslt+xml">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:template match="cities">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="city" group-by="@country">
      <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.html">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>City List</th>
            <th>Population</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/@name">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() ne 1">, </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@pop)"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>XSLT grouping example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>XSLT grouping example</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</script>

<select id="Results"></select>
<textarea id="Result"></textarea>
```

### Solely XSLT starting with an initial template

```js
transform(
  null,
  document.getElementById('XSLT').textContent,
  'None',
  document.getElementById('Result'),
  document.getElementById('Results')
);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98%;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.5/SaxonJS2.js"></script>

<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt-so-snippets/transform.js"></script>

<script id="XSLT" type="application/xslt+xml">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:param name="item-count" as="xs:integer" select="30"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $item-count">
        <item>
          <name>Item {.}</name>
          <value>{format-integer(., '0000000000' => substring(1, $item-count => math:log10() => floor() + 1))}</value>
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</script>

<select id="Results"></select>
<textarea id="Result"></textarea>
```

### JSON to JSON transformation

```js
transform(
  document.getElementById('Input').textContent,
  document.getElementById('XSLT').textContent,
  'JSON',
  document.getElementById('Result'),
  document.getElementById('Results')
);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98%;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.5/SaxonJS2.js"></script>

<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt-so-snippets/transform.js"></script>

<script id="Input" type="application/json">
[
  { "name": "item 1", "categories" : ["foo", "baz"] },
  { "name": "item 2", "categories" : ["bar", "baz"] },
  { "name": "item 3", "categories" : ["foo", "bar"] }
]
</script>

<script id="XSLT" type="application/xslt+xml">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]">
    <xsl:sequence select="array { mf:group(?*) }"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="map(*)*">
    <xsl:param name="items" as="map(*)*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$items" group-by="?categories?*">
      <xsl:map-entry key="current-grouping-key()" select="array { current-group()?name }"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</script>

<select id="Results"></select>
<textarea id="Result"></textarea>
```

Comment: *"The advantages of this would be huge to the community of XSLT questions and answers on StackOverflow'* Indeed it would.

Comment: SO decision-makers: You now have all the information, plenty of feedback - all positive!  So, when should we expect this feature to be implemented in SO: "Support the embedding of executable XSLT snippets inside questions and answers"? If nothing is done in the foreseeable future, who to blame? :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your approach to piggyback SaxonJS can be used for [XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) questions as well.
The XPath Notebooks extension for Visual Studio Code uses a precompiled SEF to achieve that.

https://github.com/DeltaXML/vscode-xpath-notebook/tree/main/resources/xslt-sef

Comment: SaxonJS supports XPath 3.1, yes, but not XQuery.

Comment: What is "[SEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEF)"? Standard Exchange Format (whatever that is)?

Comment: [Stylesheet export file](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/#!using-xsl/compiling)?

Comment: Sad to hear that. The distinction between XPath and XQuery is somewhat blurry so for a significant amount of questions this could still work out fine.

Comment: @line-o, judging from the questions I see here tagged as xquery I would say either a user of a full blown XML database like BaseX or eXist-db needs help (where I don't see XPath 3.1 samples based on SaxonJS as a viable way in 80 or more percent of the cases) or we have people using whatever some previously relational/SQL db system has added as XML query support, often calling it XQuery but usually not even being able to support e.g. all XPath 1.0 axes nor functions and more related to the use of SQL extension than XQuery or XPath, so I don't see that SaxonJS based XPath 3.1 helps there either.

Comment: Stackoverflow is already the goto spot for XSLT questions.  Having embedded execution ability would make that experience even better.